# Не переведены предлоги во временной шкале

Tags: дефект, локализация, временная-шкала

Во [временной шкале вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/820034/timeline#history_4fa4fd7e-8d58-42ea-90ad-82f150f5142d) не переведены предлоги при изменении списка дубликатов:

> [image: from-to]

Comment: Всё ещё не переведено...